# Adding capabilities to default roles

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles

I created a custom post type and gave it the following capabilities:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_team_page_post_type' );

function create_team_page_post_type() {
$args = array(
    'labels' => team_page_post_type_labels( 'Team Page' ),
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => array('team', 'teams'),
    'capabilities' => array(
            'publish_pages' => 'publish_teams',
            'edit_pages' => 'edit_teams',
            'edit_page' => 'edit_team',
            'edit_others_pages' => 'edit_others_teams',             
            'delete_pages' => 'delete_teams',
            'delete_page' => 'delete_team',
            'delete_others_pages' => 'delete_others_teams',
            'manage_pages' => 'manage_teams',
            'read_private_pages' => 'read_private_teams',               
            'read_page' => 'read_team'
        ),
    'map_meta_cap'=> true,      
    'has_archive' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array('title',
        'author',
        'editor',
        'thumbnail',
    )
);

register_post_type( 'team_page', $args );
}
```

I also checked `$GLOBALS['wp_post_types']['team_page']`to make sure they were all there and everything seems to be behaving as it should:

```
[cap] => stdClass Object
    (
        [edit_post] => edit_team
        [read_post] => read_team
        [delete_post] => delete_team
        [edit_posts] => edit_teams
        [edit_others_posts] => edit_others_teams
        [publish_posts] => publish_teams
        [read_private_posts] => read_private_teams
        [read] => read
        [delete_posts] => delete_teams
        [delete_private_posts] => delete_private_teams
        [delete_published_posts] => delete_published_teams
        [delete_others_posts] => delete_others_teams
        [edit_private_posts] => edit_private_teams
        [edit_published_posts] => edit_published_teams
        [create_posts] => edit_teams
    )
```

So I'm guessing my problem lies in incorrectly assigning these capabilities which I did like so:

```
$role_object = get_role( 'administrator' );
    $role_object->add_cap( 'publish_teams');
    $role_object->add_cap( 'edit_teams');
    $role_object->add_cap( 'edit_team');
    $role_object->add_cap( 'edit_others_teams');
    $role_object->add_cap( 'delete_teams');
    $role_object->add_cap( 'delete_team');
    $role_object->add_cap( 'delete_others_teams');
    $role_object->add_cap( 'manage_teams');        
    $role_object->add_cap( 'read_private_teams');
    $role_object->add_cap( 'read_team');
```

I thought that was the problem but when I `print_r(get_role( 'administrator' ));`
I get:

```
 WP_Role Object
(
[name] => administrator
[capabilities] => Array
    (
        [manage-teams] => 1
        [edit-teams] => 1
        [edit_others_teams] => 1
        [delete_teams] => 1
        [edit-team] => 1
        [delete_others_teams] => 1
        [delete_team] => 1
        [read_private_teams] => 1
        [read_team] => 1
        [manage_teams] => 1
    )
)
```

That list is shortened considerably.

Anyway it still doesn't work. I cannot access my custom post type as admin unless I change the capability type back to "page" or "post."

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing hyphens and underscores in the cap names you are adding to the administrator role. These don't always correspond to the caps you created.

Comment: That helped hugely. It is now appearing on the dashboard. I can view teams but I can't edit or delete them. I tidied things up and checked that I spelled team correctly but I'm still missing something.

Answer (score 0):

[There is a note in the Codex under `capability_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Parameters) that "It seems that `map_meta_cap` needs to be set to true, to make this work." Based purely on that note in the Codex I'd say you need to add...

```
'map_meta_cap' => true,
```

... to your argument list.

If that doesn't work please post all of the relevant code.

Comment: actually I already had that but I will post it with the code as t is pertinant.

Comment: I added all the relevant code I could think of. Thanks for looking. I thought I'd find more examples of this.

Comment: I will install and test that later, if no one beats me to an answer.

Comment: unlikely, especially as I'm going to bed ;)

Comment: It seems to be something with the `edit_teams, edit_team, delete_teams, delete_team` or perhaps I'm missing a capability?