# Reset default roles and capabilities

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

I've been having a difficult time adding custom post type capabilities to roles ([Adding capabilities to default roles](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/105097/adding-capabilities-to-default-roles)) and I suspect that my muddling around may have caused some problems. I also have installed and de-installed various plugins some of which added capabilities. As a result My WP Role object is a bit of a mess. Does anyone know of a way to reset capabilities or do I need a fresh install?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [User Role Editor](http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/). You can delete added roles, and reset roles from the plugin page.

To reset the administator role, you can, as of WP 3.4+, add

```
define('URE_SHOW_ADMIN_ROLE', 1);
```

to your *wp-config.php* file. After having done so, you need to go to *Users > User Role Editor* and click *"Reset"*.

Comment: Can I use it and then de-install it?

Comment: Yes, since you are just resetting the roles back to the original state, there should be no problem with deleting the plugin.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a go then.

Comment: As with any plugin, I would recommend copying your database beforehand, just in case it doesn't do what you want you always go back.

Comment: Unfortunately, It couldn't reset administrator which is the one I wanted to reset.

Comment: As long as you have WordPress 3.4+ you can add the following to your wp-config.php file

    define('URE_SHOW_ADMIN_ROLE', 1);

Comment: I tried that. Just add and save? I did `print_r(get_role( 'administrator' ));` and all my custom capabilities are still there as are those inserted by various plugins.

Comment: After adding the URE_SHOW_ADMIN_ROLE you need to go to Users > User Role Editor and click "Reset"

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. It didn't fix my problem but at least I can rule that out.

Comment: @mantis Please don't edit others' posts to add extra information. Please read http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/editing

Comment: Ok, sorry, I tried to undo the edit it but wasn't allowed.

Comment: @bungeshea Point 3 of "When should I edit posts?" (on the very page you linked to) reads "To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place" --> That's what the user mantis did. How's that not okay?

Answer (score 29):

If you don't want to install a plugin to just to do this one task, you can call the WordPress function directly to rebuild the roles and their capabilities.

```
if ( !function_exists( 'populate_roles' ) ) {
  require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/schema.php' );
}

populate_roles();
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked like a charm and was difficult to find.

Comment: This is the most simpler and robust solution that restores all the standard roles and caps in the WordPress way. This should be a selected answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I find an easier way to reset roles and their associated capabilities is to use [wp-cli](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/role/).

wp-cli has a built-in method for resetting roles. You can specify any that you want to reset. For example:

```
wp role reset author contributor editor subscriber
```

There is also an `--all` flag, which you can use like this:

```
wp role reset --all
```

Warning that this will include resetting the administrator capabilities, which may remove access to some plugins, so use with caution.